# What are the pros and cons of various ways to add remove function for array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to be able to add remove function for array. There's various ways I see I can do it:

1. Use prototype. It will allow me to write code like `arr.remove(item)`, but working with prototypes is something I would like to avoid.
2. Wrap whole array into function that will contain remove function. The cons are:

   - additional function to everything
   - I will need to write things like: `remove(arr, item);` which is fine, but not as nice as `arr.remove(item);`
3. Use [underscore][1] or [lodash](http://lodash.com/) and their methods for arrays. A good option, but have cons of #2. I feel that as underscore and lodash are popular its additional benefit as people would be able to understand your intentions.
4. Some other way to do that, that you maybe suggest.

   - One more thing I would like to note: knockoutjs observableArray have remove method. It makes sense, as observable array is wrapping js array anyway. So some additional methods added.
   - Angularjs doesnt have this kind of methods for arrays. And all the questions about array items remove suggest to use underscore Without. It seems to me, that as arrays in angular are not wrapped and pure js arrays no overhead is added. And if you need to remove element you should use some util function, like _.without or your own.

So in the end - what are the pros and cons of every of the methods?  [1]: http://underscorejs.org/#without

Comment: can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: its in the question description, all the things I tried so far. I can provide additional details is something is not clear in what I tried, just let me know.

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev out of curiosity - why do you want to avoid working with prototypes?

Comment: @aga because it will add remove function to all arrays. And I may only need it for some part of the project. Also, its considered a bad practise as it will be global. Personally I list it as one of the options, so its not something I cant do, in case I feel its a right thing todo.

Comment: This answer is going to be primarily opinion-based which is not the right form for StackOverflow.

Comment: If you add the way one should think for every option Ive mentioned and what are the pros and cons it would not be too opinion-based. And anyone who will have this kind of choice find it helpful. And at least answering that will make it easier to choose the right way.

Comment: The thing is there are a bunch of ways to do it with pros/cons for every way and, in the end, it's purely an opinion which way to select.  I don't make the rules here at StackOverflow - they say that questions whose "correct" answer is primarily opinion based are not what they want here.  I really don't know what you're asking here either.  You either add a method to the prototype or use a utility function that isn't a method and you've already proposed both options.

Comment: If you want to change your question to be what are the pros and cons of adding a method to the `Array` prototype, your question would be more of the proper form.  You aren't asking which to use, but are asking for a list of the reasons to choose one or the other.  A best answer could easily be selected and the reader would still decide which they wanted to use.

Comment: @jfriend00, I have updated the question, please, have a look. I know the rules, I just think its not that opiniated as it seems at start. Watch my angular vs knockout comparation

Comment: @jfriend00 - agree, Im asking of pros and cons. Will change the question right now.

Comment: Look at my latest comment.  I can't even find an actual question in your question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41393/discussion-between-yaroslav-yakovlev-and-jfriend00)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to reproduce the jQuery pattern (`$()`) : `$(arr).remove(item)`. Lodash already provides this feature actually : http://lodash.com/docs#_.

An interesting link : http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/.

Comment: That would mean wrap my array into function. And its additional overhead.

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev I was just looking for something between `remove(arr, item)` and `arr.remove(item)` :)

Comment: yes, these are my thoughts too :-). Im just trying to figure out if there are any additional pros/cons I'm missing. And know how to make the decision in this case. I know theres no best way to do this and it depends :-)

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev The "Downsides" part is quite interesting : http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/.

Comment: Can you put these links into your answer? I think Id vote for it :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's another way, creating a subclass of Array, but "inherit" is never easy for Javascript. This [article](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) might be helpful.

<strike>You can use [array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to achieve the elements "remove".</strike>

For example

```
array.splice(i, 1)
```

will remove the element at position i

Comment: Please, reread the question. I know the options. Its about what are the pros and cons. Wasnt stated explicitly in the title, now its there.

Comment: Reading the article now. Big thank you!